# Change horizontal alignment of list box in MATLAB R2016a to right

Tags: matlab, listbox, matlab-guide, matlab-app-designer

How we can change horizontal alignment of list box to right in MATLAB R2016 in AppDesigner or GUIDE? There isn't any available property in list box.

Comment: Which is it then - App Designer or GUIDE? These are **VERY** different things (one is based on JS/CSS and the other is on Java). If you want to do it with App Designer, you might have to manipulate the `.css` files in `%matlabroot%/toolbox/matlab/uitools/uifigureappjs/release/gbtclient/css/...` With GUIDE it should be fairly easy...

Comment: @Dev-iL. Currently I'm using AppDesigner . I mentioned two aspects to have a more general question. thanks.

Comment: Would a solution only in GUIDE be acceptable?

Comment: @Dev-iL. AppDesigner is better :-)

Comment: @Dev-iL. we have same problem in other components like radio button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can find some clues on how to do this with GUIDE in [this UndocumentedMatlab article](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/listbox-layout-customization). We need the [`findjobj`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/14317-findjobj-find-java-handles-of-matlab-graphic-objects) utility, to get a handle for the Java control. The next steps

```
function q38930371

hF = figure(...
'Position',[500 500 300 350],...
'Tag','Demo',...
'Menubar','None',...
'Resize','on');

hLb = uicontrol(...
'Parent',hF,...
'String',{  'Item 1'; 'Item 2'; 'Item 3'; 'Item 4' },...
'Style','listbox',...
'Value',1,...
'Position',[50 50 200 250],...
'Children',[],...
'Tag','listbox1');

% Get a handle to the Java control:
jSp = findjobj(hLb);

% Get the list cell renderer
jCr = jSp.getViewport.getView.getCellRenderer; 

% Set the horizontal alignment of the renderer:
% https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListCellRenderer.html
jCr.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);

% Refresh view:
jSp.repaint
```

The result:

[image: Manipulation of Swing components]

---

The **App Designer** solution can be found in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38933254/3372061).