# How to customize App Designer figures in more ways than officially documented?

Tags: matlab, dojo, customization, undocumented-behavior, matlab-app-designer

A recently published [article in UndocumentedMatlab](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/customizing-uifigures-part-1), mentions that [App Designer](http://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab/app-designer/) figures are actually web pages using the [Dojo Toolkit](https://dojotoolkit.org/). This means we *could* theoretically manipulate the HTML DOM directly to achieve certain UI customizations that are otherwise unavailable.

Below is an example of an App Designer figure definition, as appears in the `.m` file generated by the App Designer (on MATLAB R2016a):

```
classdef domDemo < matlab.apps.AppBase

    % Properties that correspond to app components
    properties (Access = public)
        UIFigure     matlab.ui.Figure          % UI Figure
        LabelListBox matlab.ui.control.Label   % List Box
        ListBox      matlab.ui.control.ListBox % Item 1, Item 2, Item 3, It...
    end

    methods (Access = private)

        % Code that executes after component creation
        function startupFcn(app)

        end
    end

    % App initialization and construction
    methods (Access = private)

        % Create UIFigure and components
        function createComponents(app)

            % Create UIFigure
            app.UIFigure = uifigure;
            app.UIFigure.Position = [100 100 260 147];
            app.UIFigure.Name = 'UI Figure';
            setAutoResize(app, app.UIFigure, true)

            % Create LabelListBox
            app.LabelListBox = uilabel(app.UIFigure);
            app.LabelListBox.HorizontalAlignment = 'right';
            app.LabelListBox.Position = [50 93 44 15];
            app.LabelListBox.Text = 'List Box';

            % Create ListBox
            app.ListBox = uilistbox(app.UIFigure);
            app.ListBox.Position = [109 36 100 74];

        end
    end

    methods (Access = public)

        % Construct app
        function app = domDemo()

            % Create and configure components
            createComponents(app)

            % Register the app with App Designer
            registerApp(app, app.UIFigure)

            % Execute the startup function
            runStartupFcn(app, @startupFcn)

            if nargout == 0
                clear app
            end
        end

        % Code that executes before app deletion
        function delete(app)

            % Delete UIFigure when app is deleted
            delete(app.UIFigure)
        end
    end
end
```

...which looks like this:

[image: Example App Designer Figure]

According to the documentation of [`uilistbox`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uilistbox.html) (which redirects us to the page on [Check Box Properties](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/checkboxappdesigner-properties.html) for the full property list), there exists no way to manipulate e.g. the text alignment of list items. If so,

> **Question**: How do we manipulate the `ListBox` in the example app such that its contents become center-aligned, even though such a setting is not available to us?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In order to succeed in this task, we need several things:

- Find where the HTML/CSS are located (so we can manipulate them).
- Find which element of the DOM we want to edit.
- Find what is the change we need to make.
- Find a way to manipulate the element using MATLAB.

---

Working step by step:

#### 1. Find where the figure's HTML/CSS are stored/located

```
win = struct(struct(struct(app).UIFigure).Controller).Container.CEF;
URL = win.URL; % Needed only for testing in browser
```

#### 2. Find which element of the DOM we need to edit

```
data_tag = char(struct(app.ListBox).Controller.ProxyView.PeerNode.getId);
```

Validation using a browser:

[image: Inspecting the page in Firefox]

#### 3. Find what is the change we need to make

Since we want to manipulate text alignment, we google some relevant keywords and find the [CSS `text-align` property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-align.asp). Then we try it manually to see if it really works:

[image]

#### 4. Find a way to manipulate the element using MATLAB

Using [`dojo.style`](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/style.html) and [`dojo.query`](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/quickstart/dom.html#css-selectors):

```
win.executeJS(['dojo.style(dojo.query("[data-tag^=''' data_tag ''']")[0],"textAlign","center")']);
```

[image: Before and after]

---

Complete code for this answer:

```
classdef domDemo < matlab.apps.AppBase

    % Properties that correspond to app components
    properties (Access = public)
        UIFigure     matlab.ui.Figure          % UI Figure
        LabelListBox matlab.ui.control.Label   % List Box
        ListBox      matlab.ui.control.ListBox % Item 1, Item 2, Item 3, It...
    end

    methods (Access = private)

        % Code that executes after component creation
        function startupFcn(app)
          % Customizations (aka "MAGIC GOES HERE"):
          drawnow; rez = [];
          warning off MATLAB:HandleGraphics:ObsoletedProperty:JavaFrame
          warning off MATLAB:structOnObject            
          while ~strcmp(rez,'"center"')
            try                
              % 1. Get a handle to the webwindow:
              win = struct(struct(struct(app).UIFigure).Controller).Container.CEF;
              % 2. Find which element of the DOM we want to edit (as before):
              data_tag = char(struct(app.ListBox).Controller.ProxyView.PeerNode.getId);    
              % 3. Manipulate the DOM via a JS command
              rez = win.executeJS(['dojo.style(dojo.query("[data-tag^=''' ...
                data_tag ''']")[0],"textAlign","center")']);
            catch
              pause(1); % Give the figure (webpage) some more time to load
            end
          end
        end
    end

    % App initialization and construction
    methods (Access = private)

        % Create UIFigure and components
        function createComponents(app)

            % Create UIFigure
            app.UIFigure = uifigure;
            app.UIFigure.Position = [100 100 260 147];
            app.UIFigure.Name = 'UI Figure';
            setAutoResize(app, app.UIFigure, true)

            % Create LabelListBox
            app.LabelListBox = uilabel(app.UIFigure);
            app.LabelListBox.HorizontalAlignment = 'right';
            app.LabelListBox.Position = [50 93 44 15];
            app.LabelListBox.Text = 'List Box';

            % Create ListBox
            app.ListBox = uilistbox(app.UIFigure);
            app.ListBox.Position = [109 36 100 74];

        end
    end

    methods (Access = public)

        % Construct app
        function app = domDemo()

            % Create and configure components
            createComponents(app)

            % Register the app with App Designer
            registerApp(app, app.UIFigure)

            % Execute the startup function
            runStartupFcn(app, @startupFcn)

            if nargout == 0
                clear app
            end
        end

        % Code that executes before app deletion
        function delete(app)

            % Delete UIFigure when app is deleted
            delete(app.UIFigure)
        end
    end
end
```